# Calculate the sum of area within the contour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

**Task:** I want to calculate the porosity of a rock sample.
So the objective is to calculate the number of pixels not covered by the rocks (white pixels).

To achieve that I calculate the number of pixels inside a contour and subtract it from the total number of pixels. Therefore the formula is **(number of white pixels) / (total number of pixels)**.

[image: Rock Sample]

**Attempt:** This is what I referred to from various sources, but applying this I am having doubts over the results. It gives a porosity of nearly **78%**, which by looking at the image shouldn't be the case. Any help will be appreciated.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

name =  'image.jpg' 
image = cv2.imread(name)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

edged = cv2.Canny(image, 30, 200)
cv2.imshow('edged', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]
area = height * width

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(edged, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255), 3)
cv2.imshow('Contours', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)

sum = 0
r = len(contours)
r1 = []

for i in range(r):
   ar1 = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
   sum += ar1
   r1.append(ar1)

print(sum) 
print(f'Porosity of {name} is: {((area - sum) / area) * 100} %')
```

Comment: your picture shows outlines. are we to interpret those as rocks with lots of interstitium, or as one big solid mass with small cavities? -- why do you think 78% is too much? what do you expect?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz So the outline refers to the outline of the solid rock, which should ideally be entirely black pixels. Just a guess it should be much lesser than 50%. Or if you feel that 78% is correct do tell.

Comment: "(number of white pixels) / (total number of pixels)" = `sum / area` = 22%

Comment: @Alpha [Labelling](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) might solve your problem ( the ratio of background pixels (not covered by rocks) to the total number of pixels)

Comment: show us pictures of 0% porosity, 50% porosity, 90% porosity. use one rectangular "rock".